# How to find an equivalent for the partial derivatives of internal energy?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy

Actually, I am trying to relate force-temperature results from one test (hydrothermal isometric tension) to heat-temperature results from another test (Differential Scanning Calorimetry). I started with the first law of thermodynamics and after some progression I obtained the following equation:

$$ \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial l}\right)_T
=f-T\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial T}\right)_l $$

where $U$ is the internal energy, $l$ is the length of the specimen, $f$ is force and $T$ is temperature. The right side of this equation is exactly what I can obtain from my HIT test but the left side is not appropriate. I am trying to change the left side of my equation to a statement which could be obtained from my DSC test. In DSC test I have enthalpy or heat flow and temperature and I don't have any length measurements. Can any of you provide a reference or some hints for me to help me with this problem?

Regards

Comment: Please enter equations using the editing tools, not as images

Comment: DSC is designed to determine the heat capacity as a function of temperature, correct?